# kubelogin convert-kubeconfig need to be invoked after every az aks get-credentials

Tags: kubectl, azure-aks

I'm having the problem described here: https://aptakube.com/blog/how-to-use-azure-kubelogin

If I follow the article and use `kubelogin convert-kubeconfig -l azurecli` it works again indeed.

The problem is that every time I refresh my credentials using `az aks get-credentialsz` I need to repeat `kubelogin convert-kubeconfig -l azurecli` otherwise it won't work.

Is there a way to make this change permanent ?